# how to set space between two pivot column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

query pivot with two word with space in column

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) SELECT

   top 24 @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, DateIn ,21 )                 + ']','[' + CONVERT(varchar, DateIn ,21) + ']'  )

      FROM    DailyAttendanceMaster  where   DateIn between '2018-10-01  00:00:00.000' and '2018-10-24 00:00:00.000'  
        DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(4000) SET
         @qry = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT Employee_Master.Employee_Name, convert(char(5), TimeIn, 108)+    + convert(char(5), TimeOutD, 108)TimeIn  , DailyAttendanceMaster.DateIn FROM DailyAttendanceMaster inner join Employee_Master on Employee_Master.essl_EmpID=DailyAttendanceMaster.EMPID)emp
          PIVOT (MAX(TimeIn) FOR DateIn IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat'  
          EXEC(@qry)
```

here is my pivot query i am concatenate two column that is TimeIn  and TimeOutD  it work correct but i want sapce between two column so how can i do it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLnHh.png)

Comment: what is your current output? and what is your expected output?

Comment: ' Employee_Name 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 2018-10-02 00:00:00.000 2018-10-03 00:00:00.000
AbhijIt Gorwadkar 10:1619:04 12:2219:03 11:3718:46'

Comment: this is my output i want space between time colum

Comment: could you please add your output in table format in the question

Comment: i have added image please see it